# Clarification on mutual singularity of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, singular-measures

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two probability measures on a measurable space, $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Then $P_1$ and $P_2$ are *mutually singular* (denoted $P_1 \perp P_2$) if there exists $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $P_1(A) = 1$ and $P_2(A) = 0$. The book *Gaussian Random Processes* by Ibragimov and Rozanov gives the following sufficient condition for mutual singularity of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

> If there exists $A_1, A_2,.... \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_1(A_n) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_2(A_n) = 1$, then $P_1 \perp P_2$.

They give the following explanation as to why, but I'm still unsure as to why this implies mutual singularity.

> We can decompose $P_2$ as $P_2 = P_2^\prime + P_2^{\prime\prime}$ where $P_2^\prime \perp P_1$ and $P_2^{\prime\prime} << P_1$. Under the condition $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_1(A_n) = 0$, we have,
> \begin{eqnarray}\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_2(A_n) &=& \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_2^\prime(A_n) + \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_2^{\prime\prime}(A_n)\\ 
> &=& \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_2^\prime(A_n)\leq P_2^\prime(\Omega) < 1 
> \end{eqnarray}

I can follow the argument they give, but not the conclusion. Why can we deduce that $P_1 \perp P_2$ in this case? If we look at the definition of mutual singularity, what are the authors using as the measurable set $A$ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P_2'(\Omega) <1$ we get a  contradiction to the assumption that $P_2(A_n) \to 1$. Hence $P_2'(\Omega) =1$. But then $P_2(\Omega) =P_2'(\Omega)+ P_2''(\Omega) $ shows that $P_2''(\Omega) =0$. Thus $P_2''$ is the zero measure. So $P_2=P_2' \perp P_1$.

Comment: The authors claim that $P_2^\prime(\Omega) < 1$ for all measures. So it seems by the wording that $P_2^\prime(\Omega) < 1$ is a fact, and not an assumption. Is this likely an error?

Comment: @Flowsnake Yes, the inequality $P_2(\Omega') <1$ is  misplaced. But what they wanted to say is clear.